# php database connection error HTTP Error 500

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

Trying to connect to a created database thats on a server and display its contents when i attempt to run it the page displays an error that states HTTP 500 error, The site may be under maintenance or could have a programming error.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

these have values, just hiding them
when i run the code through a php code checker it has a problem with the '{' on the line bellow

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Pictures ");
$conn->close();
?>
```

The HTML used to display the database

```
<html>

 <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    foreach ($row1 as $row){
 ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['hname'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['himage'] ?></td>
      <td><?php $row['hdesc'] ?></td> 
    </tr>
 <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
</body>


 </html>
```

Comment: what does your `error_log` tell you?

Comment: @delboy1978uk never came up with anything

Comment: Your mixing functions mysql_* and oop mysqli, which is it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure mysql*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Lawrence is correct, you are mixing mysql_ with mysqli_

Comment: Also `<?php $row['id'] ?>` wont print.